# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, intellij-idea, classpath, blogger

I'm getting following error while running my Spring boot app, I'm new to Spring boot and elastic search, please help to solve this issue.And attached my pom dependencies below.
Thanks in advance,

*************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START ***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers.getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Logger; but it does not exist. Its class, org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/Sudhakar/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.6.2/elasticsearch-6.6.2.jar!/org/elasticsearch/common/logging/Loggers.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/C:/Users/Sudhakar/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.6.2/elasticsearch-6.6.2.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.common.logging.Loggers

Process finished with exit code 1

**Maven dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: 2.1.1 I'm using

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot uses Elasticsearch 6.4 by default. By using 6.6.2 as the versions for two Elasticsearch modules you will have ended up with a mixture of the two versions. You should remove the `<version>` configuration in your pom. If you are able to use Spring Boot’s default version there’s nothing more to do. If you need to use 6.6.2 you should add an entry in your pom’s `<properties>`:

```
<elasticsearch.version>6.6.2</elasticsearch.version>
```